# jQuery/ajax form not working php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

HTML code:

```
<form class="contact_form" action="" name="contact_form">
<ul><li>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email here" required />
</li><li>
<button class="submit" type="submit" style="float:left" onclick="form()"onsubmit="hide_form('container_subscribe')">Send</button>
</li></ul>
</form>
```

jQuery/Ajax code :

```
$(function() {  
  $(".submit").click(function() {  
    // validate and process form here  
    var field1 = $('input[name=email]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php?f1="+field1,
    });
  });  
});
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
$to      =  $_POST['field1'];
$subject =  'the subject';
$message =  'hello';
$headers =  'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

The php script is working if I run it alone with $_GET instead of $_POST (the mail is sent) so I think ajax can't communicate with the php file.
I have no idea how to debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is you are calling the parameter `f1` in your AJAX and `field1` in your PHP.  These need to match.

You also need to write your AJAX like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "f1="+field1,
    url: "mail.php"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {  
$(".submit").click(function() {  
  // validate and process form here  
 var field1 = {'field1' : $('input[name=email]').val()};
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "mail.php",
     data: field1,
     success: function(out){ alert('Mail sended!'); },
     error: function(err){ alert(err.statusText); }
    });
  });  
});
```

Comment: error popup? can you specify?

Comment: The javascript alert popup with 'error' written inside : the error function is called.

Comment: What error type? post it

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/1e441o431z38

Comment: Try change data with data: 'field1='+$('input[name=email]').val(),

Comment: I also tried with $_POST['email'] like Dasum suggested...

Answer (score 0):

Try this below.

```
$.ajax({
     url: "mail.php",
     type: "POST", 
     data:$(".contact_form").serialize(),
     success:function(result)
         alert(result);
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     },
});
```

This will allow you to add any number of fields to the form and retrieve them by their name at the PHP level.

Comment: Not recognized apparently, I think it's the fourth line that is not working...

Comment: when you retrieve data you must use $_POST['email']; in the php